# Valueinjecter map base derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mapping, valueinjecter

I have a base class `Ad`.

```
public class Ad
{
    public int Id{get;set;}

    public string Title{get;set;}

    public string Price{get;set;}
}
```

Then I have a lot of derived classes like:

```
public class CarAd : Ad
{
    public string ModelName {get;set;}
}

public class MobileAd : Ad
{
    public string CompanyName {get;set;}
}
```

And accordingly I have ViewModels for these classes as well.

```
public class AdViewModel
{
    public int Id{get;set;}

    public string Title{get;set;}

    public string Price{get;set;}
}

public class CarAdViewModel : AdViewModel
{
    public string ModelName {get;set;}
}

public class MobileAdViewModel : AdViewModel
{
    public string CompanyName {get;set;}
}
```

I am trying to map derived class with base class using value injecter. Like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] CarAdViewModel carAdModel)
    {
        var ad = new Ad();
        ad.InjectFrom(carAdModel);
    }
```

But it is not mapping properties of derived class. Can somebody tell me if it is possible?

Comment: carAdViewModel has ModelName property, and Ad doesn't has it, what did you expect it to do ? maybe you need to use CarAd instead of Ad

Comment: But carAd is inherited by Ad class and I am passing derived class into InjectFrom. So can't it convert Ad into CarAd like polymorphism?

Comment: Ad is inherited by carAd and you're passing the base class Ad